# Cannot extend class using Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend a class that exists as a node_module.

My extended class has no access to the parent's prototype.

Here's a link to a repro:

https://bitbucket.org/IamHttP/repro-types/src/master/

Here's an image that shows this behaviour in WebStorm

As you can see, one has access to `destroy()` and one does not.

[image]

Comment: Did you run it to check if it is weird behavior of WebStorm ?

Comment: yea ofcourse :) typescript itself is not compiling even from the command line.

Comment: Do you think you could reproduce this in a web IDE so that people who want to help can do so without npm installing code on their machines?   Also, as mentioned in [ask], it's a good idea that any [mcve] example be included as text in your question, not only as an external link or as a picture.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for hte input @jcalz - I was sure the issue is related to a node module, so I guess I had to provide a real example with a node_module. I'll take note for future questions. I tried to be as informative as possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type definition for Entity is not properly exported from the first package.  Use `Go to Definition` on `game-platform` in your second project and you'll see this in your first package's types:

```
import Entity from 'lib/ECS/Entity';
import entityLoop from 'lib/ECS/util/entityLoop';
import ObjectPool from 'lib/ObjectPool/ObjectPool';
import GameCanvas from 'lib/GameCanvas/GameCanvas';
import Engine from 'lib/Engine/Engine';
...
```

It is typed as `any` on import in the consuming project, because that path cannot be resolved. Changing it to this in the first package makes it work as expected:

```
import Entity from './lib/ECS/Entity';
```

Comment: Wow good find. I also took a look. Looks like this might be a good idea to add a stricter configuration. My typescript will warn me on bad exports and imports that don't have types.

Comment: No implicit any might do it. You can use eslint to disallow any at all.

Comment: Thanks! I started investigating down that path myself, I found a closed issue with typescript that it does not re-write the import paths in generated files - this is really unfortunate as I'd like to use alias paths in my projects instead of `../../../../../` hell - Much appreciated @JoshWulf

Answer (score 0):

`destroy` method is probably private.

```
class A {
  private a;
  constructor() {

  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

const b = new B();
b.a; // Error
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not actually private, I control both packages. also, the JS part does work (if compile by force I have access to destroy in real JS code)